# Titlecasing UITableViewHeader Label

Tags: ios, swift

I have a grouped UITableView that I've laid out in a storyboard and I want to change the title of each section from uppercased to titlecased.

What's the cleanest way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Show your implementation of `titleForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: All I currently do is switch on the section and return a specific string per section

Comment: Then return the titlecased version of the string.

Comment: I do, seems like it's maybe overwritten by some storyboard setting?

Answer (score 0):

This'll do it:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    guard let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }
    header.textLabel?.text = header.textLabel?.text?.capitalized
}
```